# emit class with a property of the same type as declaring emitted type

Tags: c#, reflection.emit

I have found how to emit a class, like this:

```
class MyClass
{
    String MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Cannot figure out how to emit the following:

```
class MyClass
{
    MyClass MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

The problem I faced is:

In order to emit the setter and getter, I need a variable representing the final compiled/emitted Type. In order to emit this Type, I need to emit setter/getter first. I guess it is possible, because the language allows that in static compilation.

Comment: You used TypeBuilder.CreateType().  It returns a Type, that egg went before the chicken.  Nobody can see you doing this wrong.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: MSDN help states TypeBuilder.CreateType() loads the type under construction and requires fields and methods defined. "Creates a Type object for the class. After defining fields and methods on the class, CreateType is called in order to load its Type object." It would work if CreateType returned the same type, regardless of whether it is called with all properties and methods defined.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> In order to emit the setter and getter, I need a variable representing the final compiled/emitted Type

Actually, you don't: you just need to pass the `TypeBuilder` as the type of the property (`TypeBuilder` inherits from `Type`, so it's a valid argument for the `returnType` parameter of `DefineProperty`)

Comment: Thanks. It means I could probably use TypeBuilder as an argument to MakeGeneric in order to emit a call something like this: MyClass MyProperty { get { return ReadMyPropertyAs<MyClass>(...); }} Is that technically correct? I would expect it to be correct if myTypeBuilder.CreateType() was equal to just myTypeBuilder (i.e. myTypeBuilder.CreateType() == myTypeBuilder).

Comment: @Andrew, AFAIK, you can use a `TypeBuilder` anywhere a `Type` is expected. It doesn't matter that it's not actually the same thing as the emitted type, because in the emitted code, it will still resolve to the same metadata token, and at runtime, it will use the emitted type.